# keeping swipe up down as default using hammer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hammer.js

I'm using hammer js for swipe gestures on any mobile table. its a simple swipe left/right goto next/back.

But what i want it up/down to remain as they are (scroll up/down).

The code is pretty straightforward, the issues is when i do swipe up/down the page  scroll up/down abnormally. At times it doesn't scroll at all or it scrolls a tiny bit up or down.

```
function hammerEvent( event ){

    if(event.type == 'swipe' ){
        if(event.direction == 'left'){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.location = gNext.href              
        }
        if(event.direction == 'right'){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.location = gBack.href  
        }

    }
}
```

Any one experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response but still...

If you use rather old version of Hammer (about 0.6) - you could pass an appropriate parameter into it's options like

```
var hammer1 = new Hammer(element, {
    drag_vertical: false,
    swipe: false
});
```

I'm not sure about newer versions but it seems that you should just pass other parameters (smth like `drag_block_vertical: true`). See more about params at the [Hammer page](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started).